# Can an included file read the parents $_GET parameters?

Tags: php, include, query-string

In my php page, I recieve a bunch of get parameters. can a file I include read these too?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but you might wanna watch out for security flaws in that method. Someone might include a file that you don't want shown.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> can a file I include read these too?

Yes. An included file behaves like normal code in the original file, with all the original variables and scope intact.

The only differences are the `__FILE__`, `__DIR___` and `__LINE__` constants that will point to the include file's path and directory.